# Radial dependence of a spherical energy density, gravity, and black holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mass

To motivate my question, I'll share an example from Carroll. Carroll shows that if we have a simple model of a star as a perfect fluid characterized by some coordinate-dependent pressure $p$, energy density $\rho$, and radial coordinate $R$, the Schwarzschild parameter $M$ outside of the star is simply $\int_0^R \rho(r) 4 \pi r^2 dr$. However, Carroll notes that the integrated energy density $\bar{M}$ using the induced metric will be $\bar{M} = \int_0^R \frac{\rho(r)}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2G}{r}\int_0^{r}\rho(r') 4\pi r'^2 dr'  }} 4 \pi r^2 dr > M$. He intuits the difference as the effect of negative gravitational binding energy. Note that the weak-field limit of the Schwarzschild metric shows that a faraway observer would feel the effects of the star like a Newtonian observer near a star of mass $M$.

My point of interest is that we will suffer different $M$ values for a fixed $\bar{M}$ (and vice-versa) if we change how the energy is distributed within our simple model of a star. That is, I interpret this result as that we no longer enjoy "Gauss's law for gravity." (Ultimately, I believe the energy density will be decided by the requirements of hydrostatic equilibrium and the introduction of some equation of state relating pressure and energy density, as discussed in Carroll).

On stackexchange, users like Rob Jefferies have [noted that](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195973) we might expect "a significant reduction in the gravitational mass compared with the baryonic mass" for a neutron star.

---

Now for my question. Consider a black hole, where far from the black hole in the weak field limit an observer feels the effects of gravity like that from a Newtonian object of mass $M$. I'll call $M$ the *faraway mass*. (Though Schwarzschild has a clear definition of mass $M$ through the metric and through e.g. the Komar mass, I would prefer to consider the mass $M$ in terms of the leading order geodesics in the weak-field limit far away from the black hole. )

Are the above considerations of the distribution of energy density important in finding the value of $M$? If I have some relatively localized, relatively small energy density corresponding to some total energy $m$ far from the black hole and it drifts into the black hole and enough time passes to reach some equilibrium metric, should I expect that my observer will (eventually, after some time) feel a faraway mass of $M+m$ or a faraway mass less than $M+m$? (I expect less because of radiated energy.) How can I determine the faraway mass my distant observer will feel - do I need to solve all the intermediate dynamics in the style of an initial value GR problem and find the radiated energy, or can I use some other method to extract out just the final faraway mass?

Answer (score 1):

In an asymptotically flat spacetime, we have two well-known measures of mass, the Bondi mass and the ADM mass. They differ because the Bondi mass doesn't include energy being radiated away to null infinity by gravitational waves, whereas the ADM mass does. The ADM mass is conserved. In your example, a distant observer will feel a mass of $M+m$ at all times, assuming gravitational radiation is negligible.

> That is, I interpret this result as that we no longer enjoy "Gauss's law for gravity."

The ADM mass is precisely what you get by applying Gauss's law at infinity.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the ADM mass is what I get by applying Gauss's law at infinity. I'm trying to define a "faraway mass" in terms of what a distant observer would feel in a weak-field Newtonian limit, where by feel I'm referring to the Christoffel symbols / the geodesic the distant observer travels upon. Is this "faraway mass" equal to the Bondi mass?

Comment: @user196574: What you're talking about is the ADM mass. Applying Gauss's law at infinity is the same as using the definition of a distant observer applying the Newtonian limit.

Comment: I think one point of confusion for me is reconciling ADM's conservation with the distant observer definition. I feel that if energy is carried off by gravitational waves, then my distant (but not infinitely far) observer should eventually experience a smaller force of gravity in the Newtonian limit. However, I feel that if ADM includes gravitational waves and is conserved, then the distant observer wouldn't experience a smaller force of gravity even with radiation should we identify ADM and the distant observer definition. I'll chew on that some more.

Comment: It is somewhat misleading to say that the ADM mass will be $M+m$ at all times. This suggests for example that the ADM mass of a neutron star should be equal to its baryonic mass, which it isn't.