# What portion of a neutron star's mass is in the form of gravitational energy?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, neutron-stars

The reason this question is being asked is that in the case of black holes around 100% of their mass is stored in their gravitational field and I am wondering if neutron stars come close.

It is known that neutron stars store a good portion of their mass in the form of neutrons but is it possible for them to have gravitational energy and would that be significant? What portion of the mass of a neutron star is converted into gravitational energy?

Comment: _in the case of black holes around 100% of their mass is stored in their gravitational field_ Why do you think so ? Black hole mass is concentrated below the event horizon, while it's gravitational field extends far into the outer-space outside of event horizon. Besides in what matter form black hole mass is stored,- nobody knows at all, it's the fresh frontier of astrophysics and/or quantum gravity,- a research work which still needs to be done.

Comment: There are some subtleties to how we even _define_ how much of the mass-energy is gravitational, but note that $\frac{3GM^2}{5Rc^2}=\frac{3R_s}{10R}$ for a mass $M$ of Schwarzschild radius $R_s:=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$ much smaller than the radius $R$ the mass occupies.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas he says it because Kip Thorne says it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oj1AfkPQa6M

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the binding energy of a neutron star?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195951/what-is-the-binding-energy-of-a-neutron-star)